# Why is Dave Lister clean-shaven?

Tags: red-dwarf

Lister is supposed to be a slob, characterized as shunning washing, soap, and fresh underwear.

Is there an in-universe explanation of why he always clean shaven (except for a flash forward where he is very old and has a full beard)? A slob, if he shaved, would not be perfectly clean-shaven.

He is certainly not a eunuch as he has intercourse with his bizarro female self ;-)

Comment: Space depilatories.

Comment: Would a slob bother with those?

Comment: don't see why not. If I were in charge of the space ship, I'd have them be their own head in the 'fresher.

Comment: Slob? I think you're confused with when the Cat lost his vanity in the episode _Polymorph_. Now that's what I'd call a slob.

Comment: Maybe hair is the one thing he cares about... He is pretty fond of his three dreadlocks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He shaves because it's part of his general cleaning routine. The script directions for Future Echoes indicate that this makes him feel "fresh".

Note that although Dave's personal habits would make a hobo blush, he isn't usually *filthy*.

> **LISTER freshening himself up**, which for LISTER means reaching under
> his T-shirt to scratch with one hand and spray under his arms with the
> other.
>
> **LISTER:** (Singing) *To Ganymede and Titan, yes sir, I've been around, but there ain't no place in the whole of space like that good
> old toddlin' town.*
>
> He picks up another spray can in his free hand and sprays his face.
>
> **LISTER:** *Oh, Lunar Ci-*
>
> He suddenly realises that he's spraying his face with underarm
> deodorant. Cautiously reaching under his shirt, he discovers that he's
> been spraying shaving foam under his arms. He scrapes off a handful
> and slaps it on his face.
>
> <sub><sup>[Red Dwarf: Future Echoes - Script](http://gelfspace.tripod.com/12script.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: So he does shave at least occasionally, but is it really consistent that he shaves so frequently to be perfectly cleanshaven?  I'm too lazy to shave. Is Lister really better than I?

Comment: Spaceman Dave was very brave. He didn't wash and didn't shave. He taught rogue scrudders to behave. But Dave's friend Rimmer was even dimmer.

Comment: @ClintEastwood - Based on the fact that he's clean-shaven (or at least not bearded) we can assume that he shaves daily, along with the rest of his cleaning routine such as turning his underwear inside out.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Most slobby people I've known have never wanted to feel dirty, they simply didn't care about or notice certain things. I can believe that Lister neatly shaving himself satisfies his psychological urge for cleanliness even though he doesn't care about a shower or clean underwear. Out of universe, it's hard to keep a consistent level of stubble for filming, and the audience is more likely to relate to someone who doesn't look too far gone.

Comment: In the recent series of Red Dwarf, number 11 shown in the UK in September 2016 there is a scene where Kryten is shown to perform the task of shaving Dave Lister. I cannot remember which episode it is in though,

Comment: Season 11 isn't considered canonical because it sucks too hard. No Holly? WTF!